# No static method saveAttributeDataForStyleable in class Landroidx/core/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes

Tags: java, android

I keep getting this exception in my Android app when inflating a View located from a separate library. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method saveAttributeDataForStyleable in class or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat'...`.

The other posts I've found related to this are suggest upgrading android support libraries, however I am using androidx libraries ( androidx.core 1.2.0 and androidx.appcompat 1.2.0). **Also note for complicated business reasons I cannot upgrade the version of androidx.core used in com.myapp (1.2.0)**, however I *can* change the version used in com.mylibrary. Which is why I have this problem in the first place.

I found that `saveAttributeDataForStyleable` is located in androidx.core 1.3.0, but not in 1.2.0, so I switched everything in com.mylibrary to use androidx.core 1.2.0. However my com.myapp is still throwing the exception. I also already tried excluding the androidx.core library from the com.mylibrary dependency in com.myapp's build.gradle, so that the final app would reference androidx.core 1.2.0 anyway, but that also didn't work.

The app is com.myapp which has a library com.mylibrary.
SimpleView which has the inflate exception is located in com.mylibrary, which is another package I own that I've published my mavenLocal(). com.mylibrary is using `androidx.core 1.2.0` and `androidx.appcompat 1.2.0`.

**build.gradle of com.mylibrary:**

```
{
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0") {
        exclude group: "androidx.core", module: "core"
    }
    implementation("androidx.core:core:1.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2"){
        exclude group: "androidx.core", module: "core"
    }
}
```

**build.gradle of com.myapp:**

```
implementation("com.mylibrary") {
    exclude group: "androidx.core", module: "core"
}
```

Full exception:

```
com.myapp.views:layout/my_layout: Error inflating class com.mylibrary.SimpleView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44 in com.myapp.views:layout/my_layout: Error inflating class com.mylibrary.SimpleView
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at com.mylibrary.ParentSubView.<init>(Unknown Source:55)
        at com.mylibrary.ParentView.<init>(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.mylibrary.ParentView.<init>(Unknown Source:16)
        at com.myapp.MyStore.setupParentView(MyStore.kt:94)

     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method saveAttributeDataForStyleable(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/content/Context;[ILandroid/util/AttributeSet;Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;II)V in class Landroidx/core/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/app/com.myapp/base.apk)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:51)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:83)
        at com.mylibrary.SimpleView.<init>(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.mylibrary.SimpleView.<init>(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.mylibrary.SimpleView.<init>(Unknown Source:11)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Comment: With Core 1.7.0 out (and 1.8.0 right afterwards), you'll find that more and more libraries are going to be pulling in newer versions of Core (and AndroidX *only* upgrades dependencies if they actually need new APIs from those dependencies) and your inability to update is going to hamstring you more and more.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Unfortunately I don't own com.myapp (the one using 1.2.0), but I will bring this up to that business in the hopes they change things.

Answer (score 1):

> Also note for complicated business reasons I cannot change the version
> of androidx.core used in com.myapp, even though I can change the version used in com.mylibrary, which is why I'm stuck with using androidx.core:1.2.0 in the first place.

I figured it out. Breaking down the error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method saveAttributeDataForStyleable(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/content/Context;[ILandroid/util/AttributeSet;Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;II)V in class Landroidx/core/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/app/com.myapp/base.apk)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:51)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:83)
        at com.mylibrary.SimpleView.<init>(Unknown Source:5)
```

- This is saying `saveAttributeDataForStyleable` is missing. I implemented androidx.core 1.2.0 and androidx.core 1.3.0 in my source code and was able to find that **saveAttributeDataForStyleable was introduced in androidx.core **1.3.0****. This means com.mylibrary.SimpleView, which extends AppCompatImageView, **is somehow still referencing a newer version of androidx.core (androidx.core.1.3.0+) when it's getting compiled and published as a library to my local maven repository**. This results in my SimpleView.class file still having saveAttributeDataForStyleable() in it.
- Then, when com.myapp is running and goes to inflate com.mylibrary.SimpleView, it sees the call to saveAttributeDataForStyleable() in AppCompatImageView and attempts to call it. But since com.myapp only has androidx.core 1.2.0 in it's dependencies, it can't find that function in any of com.myapp's source files. This is what is meant by `No such method...or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/app/com.myapp/base.apk)`.

So from above, I deduced that **androidx.core 1.3.0 or higher was still lurking in my com.mylibrary dependency graph.**

I ran `./gradle dependencies` from com.mylibrary to find that androidx.core was actually resolving to androidx.core 1.7.0 because of a dependency of another dependency. Also androidx.core was showing up in so many places in the dependency graph that I just put this at the top of my build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core') {
            details.useVersion "1.2.0"
        }
    }
}
```

**But then** I still was getting the exception. How was androidx.core 1.3.0+ still getting into my project?

I finally looked at the class AppCompatBackgroundHelper (which I should have done in the first place) and it's located in the androidx.appcompat library. My com.mylibrary package was using androidx.appcompat 1.2.0 so I went to Maven repository to see appcompat's dependencies: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.appcompat/appcompat

And under 1.2.0 you can see its Compile Dependencies are androidx.core:1.1.0. Doh. So even though I excluded androidx.core from the appcompat line of my build.gradle, that isn't enough because the AppCompatImageView in that library makes a clear call to saveAttributeDataForStyleable() and thus imports androidx.core:1.3.0 files as a dependency anyway.

The final solution was switching the build.gradle in my com.mylibrary to:

```
{
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.core:core:1.2.0")
  
  
 implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2")
  
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core') {
            details.useVersion "1.2.0"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.appcompat') {
            details.useVersion "1.1.0"
        }
    }
```

And I added the last line for safe measure.

After compiling com.mylibrary and publishing to mavenLocal(), and importing into com.myapp, everything worked.

Comment: Bless you for this great explanation. Adding the resolutionStrategy for androidx.appcompat fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.saveAttributeDataForStyleable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).